# Why didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler is called but usual didReceiveRemoteNotification isn't?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, apple-push-notifications

In my application I have two types of push notifications: remote silent notifications with `content-available = 1` flag and usual push notifications with `body`, `badge` and other stuff.

I also define two delegate methods `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` and usual `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

But when a push-notification without `content-available` flag arrives `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` is called, instead of  `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

How to fix this?
Why can't I have two delegate methods for background and usual pushes?

Comment: Does `content-available` affect method to be invoked? I think setting `remote-notification` as a background mode causes `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` to invoke.

Comment: "Does content-available affect method to be invoked?" - No. I said  that `but when usual push-notification without content-available flag arrives nevertheless didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler is called`. So this delegate is called regardless `content-available` flag is set or not.

Comment: Then, is't because of `remote-notification` background mode.

Comment: @vokilam As I understood "because of remote-notification background mode" iOS will always call  only new `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler ` instead of `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and there is no way to change this, right?

Comment: I guess, there's no way. Because usual push notifications are also allowed to be processed in background.

Comment: @vokilam "Because usual push notifications are also allowed to be processed in background." really? As far as I know `didReceiveRemoteNotification`is called only when the app is in foreground

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47760/discussion-between-vokilam-and-harrydeveloper1212)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

iOS 7 only calls the new one, this is how I handled it in my app:

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    // Pass on
    [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:nil];

}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    // Check if in background
    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

        // User opened the push notification

    } else {

        // User hasn't opened it, this was a silent update

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. You said: "iOS 7 only calls the new one" but why you do this: `  // Pass on
    [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:nil];` if this method won't be called?

Comment: iOS 6 and below still call the old one, so that just passes it on to the new one when running on old versions of iOS...